# show records from database using the first 3 character if match and ignore the rest of the string

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

I want to bring those records which match the first 3 characters.
e.g a zip code (5BS 3js). if user type 5BS...(... any character after 5BS) so i want to show those records which match 5BS only and ignore the rest of the keywords. laravel eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Like** operator. To match only words starting by **your_prefix**, you can use the **wildcard %**.

If you want to search only words beginning by a specific pattern, the syntax is `prefix%`

With this syntax, the **Like** operator will search all occurrences starting by **prefix**.

```
$zipCodePrefix = '5BS';
$records = DB::table('table_name')
  ->where('zip_code', 'LIKE', $zipCodePrefix.'%')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.